# Can I use a bitbucket app password to get an authentication token

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to add a feature to my application that would let it's users create an issue directly on bitbucket if they encounter a bug. I've created a bitbucket account that the app will use to upload issues through.
For authentication I'm using the OAuth 2.0 Password grant type and my understanding of the documentation is that I should be able to use an "app password" when authenticating but I haven't had luck as yet. Is my approach at all possible or should I be going about this another way?

Answer (score 0):

The App Password should be used when authenticating via Basic Auth. My mistake was trying to use the App Password to get an authentication token via OAuth2.0 (Using the password grant type flow).